# How to resolve "Allow attribute will take precedence over allowfullscreen" warning?

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-browser

`Allow attribute will take precedence over 'allowfullscreen'.`

I'm getting this warning message because I've added an iframe with both `allow="fullscreen" and allowfullscreen`.

`allow` doesn't seem to work in IE, Edge, or Firefox, according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe.

How can I resolve/silence this warning message in a cross-browser compatible way?

Here's a minimal snippet to reproduce the warning message in Chrome:

```
const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.setAttribute('allowFullScreen', '');
iframe.setAttribute('allow', 'fullscreen');
```

Answer (score 8):

Turns out swapping the order of those `setAttribute` lines silences the warning:

```
const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.setAttribute('allow', 'fullscreen'); // must be 1st
iframe.setAttribute('allowFullScreen', '');
```

Answer (score 6):

On a Vimeo embed iFrame, remove `allowFullScreen` altogether.

From

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/000000000" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
```

To

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/000000000" allow="autoplay; fullscreen"></iframe></div>
```

Comment: We’ve updated our embed code generation on Vimeo.com to only include the allow attribute, so you shouldn’t see the warning anymore when using the update embed code.

If you have existing embeds, you can remove the allowfullscreen attribute if your target browsers don’t require it.